# Vb.net Excel Subtotals into variables

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I've got Visual Basic Application that creates excel sheets based on the years, now in every excel sheet there will be subtotals of the given period that has been entered into the application. The total is being created by this:

```
oSheet.Range("F" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,F" & summaryPosition & ":F" & j & ")"
oSheet.Range("G" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,G" & summaryPosition & ":G" & j & ")"
oSheet.Range("H" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,H" & summaryPosition & ":H" & j & ")"
oSheet.Range("I" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,I" & summaryPosition & ":I" & j & ")"
oSheet.Range("J" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,J" & summaryPosition & ":J" & j & ")"
```

Now i need to save these totals to a variable, but i have no idea how to get the totals into there. Anyone ever worked with Excel this way and knows how to solve this?

**EDIT**
I want to reference to the subtotal in the sheet, but i do not know how that works in Vb.net, any one an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with 
`DIM var1 as oSheet.Range("F" & j + 1).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,F" & summaryPosition & ":F" & j & ")"` 
it must get the result of that in `var1`